# Angular - Dynamic component in mat-tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-dynamic-components

I have a mat-tab-group (angular material) and I want to be able to add from code behind mat-tabs including other components. I am using ComponentFactoryResolver to create the component but I am not able to add the new component to the new mat-tab through the ViewContainerRef

html

```
<mat-tab-group>
 <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs"  [label]="tab.title">
  <div #test></div>
 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

code behind

```
private open(type:string):void{
 var tab = {title:'test'};
 this.tabs.push(tab);

 const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DiscountGridComponent );
 //this will add it in the end of the view
 const newComponentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why not just add the components you need with their directive? i.e. <app-component></app-component>

Comment: I am going to have a menu and I will open new tabs with different components according to what it has been selected from the menu.

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to share what I came up with, in case it helps anyone else:

```
export class DynamicTabComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public tabs = [ComponentOne, ComponentTwo];

    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false}) public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.renderComponent(0);
    }

    public tabChange(index: number) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderComponent(index);
        });
    }

    private renderComponent(index: number) {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.components[index]);
        this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="tabChange($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Tab" *ngFor="let component of components">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <div #container></div>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 2):

On angular 13 its quite simpler because you don't need to inject the componentFactory service anymore.

My solution was to use a `ViewChildren` and create the components inside the tabs right on the component ngAfterViewInit
html:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of tabs [label]="item.label">
        <div #tabContainer></div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

ts

```js
export class AdminTabsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChildren('tabContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) public tabContainerList: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

    @Input() tabsInfo: TabsInfoModel;

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.populateViewContainersWithComponents();
    }

    private populateViewContainersWithComponents(): void {
        this.tabContainerList.toArray().forEach((container, index) => {
            container.createComponent(this.tabs[index].component);
        });
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also replaced the BrowserAnimationsModule and used NoopAnimationsModule instead.

```
    export class DynamicTabComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public tabs = [ComponentOne, ComponentTwo];

    @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false}) public 
    viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.renderComponent(0);
    }

    public tabChange(index: number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.renderComponent(index);
    });
    }

    private renderComponent(index: number) {
    const factory = 
this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.components[index]);
this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
}
}
```

The Template

```
    <mat-tab label="Tab" *ngFor="let component of components">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
        <div #container></div>
    </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

The Module

```
 imports: [
  CommonModule,
  MaterialModuleSet,
  BrowserModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  AppRoutingModule,
  NoopAnimationsModule
// BrowserAnimationsModule]        removed the BrowserAnimationModule
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022**, Angular v14 but applicable to lower versions as well.

@LeonardoRick solution is very proper.

Nevertheless, there is another solution, more adequate to Angular docs official example for dynamic component loader ([link to docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)).

So, there is proposal to make a usage of `directive`, which has defined `viewContainerRef`.

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[adHost]',
    })
    export class AdDirective {
      constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
    }
```

This directive in a component is defined with `ViewChild`:

```
  @ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost!: AdDirective;
```

---

So, how to apply above solution to asked question and render multiple dynamic components?

**Solution:**
Directive keeps the same. However in component, instead of using `ViewChild` there will used `ViewChildren` and `QueryList` as above:

```
  @ViewChildren(AdComponentDirective) _adComponentDirective: QueryList<AdComponentDirective>;
```

Due to usage of `QueryList` there must be applied also `ngAfterViewInit`  lifecycle hook cuz right then the `QueryList` is ready and loaded. Have a closer look at `populateViewContainersWithComponents` method, in which is dynamic components assignment to tabs.

```
export class AdminTabsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChildren(AdComponentDirective) adComponentDirective!: QueryList<AdComponentDirective>;

    @Input() tabsInfo: TabsInfoModel;

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.populateViewContainersWithComponents();
    }

    private populateViewContainersWithComponents(): void {
        this._dynamicComponentDirective.toArray().forEach((container, index) => {
      container.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.tabs[index].component);
    });
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

In the template:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of tabs; index as i" label="{{ item.label }}">
    <ng-template adHost></ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```