# How can I implement dynamic tabs in angular using angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a dynamic tabs, where first tab will display a list of employees and on clicking the employee id it should open that employee in edit mode in new tab similar to [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-tabs).

The only difference is I want to use angular material for this purpose.

Any pointer or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/dynamic-tab-based-application-using-angular-material-9f9da7de5732

Comment: From what I understand you want tabs to appear once the user hits an add button or something happens, right? If you tab is expected to shoe data from a corresponding model, you could simply create a new instance of that model and push it into an array, which is bound to the list of tabs. When that list changes, the changes are displayed - be it adding, renaming or deleting a tab. It all would depend on that array of models beneath it.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498869/angular-dynamic-component-in-mat-tab/60878427#60878427